# Returning result of palindrome program using while-loop

Tags: python

```
n = str(input('Enter the string:'))
def palindrome(n):
    index = 0
    check = True
    while index<int(len(n)/2):
        if n[index]==n[-1-index]:
            index+=1
            return True
            break
        return False
if palindrome(n)==True:
    print('palindrome')
else:
    print('not palindrome')
```

I am not getting the correct answer for this palindrome program.

Comment: What version of Python? 2 or 3?

Comment: Why even use that function if you could do `print("palindrome" if n == n[::-1] else "not palindrome")`?

Comment: @roganjosh: python 3.4

Comment: What is it failing on? I've tried odd and even length inputs and it's been right

Comment: Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter the string:athira
palindrome
#this is the error iam getting. only the first and last characters are been checked

Comment: Your function checks the opposite of a palindrome. You return `False` if *no* pairs match, and `True` if *any* pairs match. You should return `False` if *any* pair does not match, and `True` if *all* pairs match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic solution:

```
def palindrome(n):
    start = 0
    end = len(n) - 1
    while (start < end):
        if (n[start] != n[end]):
            return False
        start = start + 1
        end = end - 1
    return True
```

Comment: so where do i call the fuction palindrome()

Answer (score 1):

Use raw_input:

```
n = str(raw_input('Enter the string:'))
```

Comment: The program  works in this way with Canopy using 2.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(my_string):
    reverse_string = my_string[::-1]
    if list(my_string)==list(reverse_string):
       return True
    else:
       return False
my_string = input("ENTER THE STRING ")
if(palindrome(my_string)):
    print("Palindrome")
else:
    print("Not Palindrome")
```

Comment: actually i need a python program without using reversed() function.

Comment: use reverse_string = my_string[::-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
while index < int(len(n) / 2):
    if n[index] != n[len(n) - index - 1]:
        return False
    index+=1
return True
```

Comment: You are welcome, Athira. If it's the best answer please check that as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: iam really sorry to say that its not returning the correct answer.. :-(

Comment: n = str(input('Enter the string:'))
def palindrome(n):
    index = 0
    check = True
    while index < int(len(n)/2):
        if n[index] != n[len(n) - 1]:
            return False
        index+=1
    return True
            
        
if palindrome(n)==True:
    print('palindrome')
else:
    print('not palindrome')

Comment: This answer provides no context. Could you explain how this works?

Comment: The context is in the question title, James.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: yaaa... now it works.. its because of the statement index+=1. due to the indented block error the output for this program gone wrong. Anyway thank you so much. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Your check is broken. Look at `return True`:

```
def palindrome(n):
    index = 0
    check = True
    while index<int(len(n)/2):
        if n[index]==n[-1-index]:
            index+=1  # only increment on match !!!
            return True  # return True on *first* match !!!
            break  # unnecessary, return exits the loop
        return False  # never reached, but would only trigger if there are no matches
```

Basically, you go through your string and on the first *match* you report True. So if first and last letter are the same, `True` is returned. Only if *no* pair of characters matches, you return `False`. This is the opposite of what want to check. It should be this instead:

```
def palindrome(n):
    index = 0
    check = True
    while index < len(n)/2:
        if n[index] != n[-1-index]:
            return False  # one didn't match, cannot be a palindrome
        index+=1
    return True  # all did match, is a palindrome
```

Comment: the same error is been occurred while trying this code too